# 'height:100%' is not working?

Tags: html, css, height

I'm working in a [website](http://alumnodaw.esy.es/programacion/)  with the  header and the main menu working as a column in the left side while I have the content on the right side.

No matter what I do, I can’t make the header grow with the content. For some reason,  the body gets stuck at some point and it won’t allow the divs inside it work properly.

I tried all I could see throughout the web: I’m working with relative positions and I think all of the containers have height:100%

Any ideas on how can I fix this?:(

Here you go my source code if this can be helpful.

```css
html{
  height:100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0; 
  font-size: 1em; 
  line-height: 1.4; 
  font-family: Arial;
  height:100%
 }

a { 
  color: #6a6a6a; 
  text-decoration: none; 
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline; 
}

a:hover, a:active { 
  outline: 0; 
}

p.copyright {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 7px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}   

#container{
  height:100%;
}

div.main    {
    padding: 0 0 33px 0;
  width:75%;
  position:relative;
  float:right;
  height:100%;

}

.page-header    {
    background: #d60362;
    color: #fff;
    width: 20%;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
    padding: 12px 17px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
  height:100%;
}

.page-header h1 {
    margin: 0 0 4px 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 260px;
    height: 110px;
  text-align: center;
}

.page-header h1 a   {
    display: block;
    width: 260px;
    height: 105px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.strapline  {
    color: #3d3d3d;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 26px 0;
  text-align:center;
}

.page-header a  {
    color: #fff;
}
.page-header a:hover    {
    color: #3d3d3d;
  text-decoration:none;
}

#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu a {
  line-height: 1.3;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: 250px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  background: #d60362;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a > span {
  background: #d60362;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active {
  border-bottom: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  color: #fff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a span {
  background: #83003C;
}
#cssmenu span.cnt {
  display:none;
}
/* Sub menu */
#cssmenu ul ul {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  border-top: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a {
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  color: #d60362;
  font-size: 13px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {
  color: #83003C;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.odd {
  background: #f4f4f4;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.even {
  background: #fff;
}

#posts{
  width:90%;
  margin:15px 20px 50px 50px;
  height:100%;
}

#posts h1{
  color:#d60362;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:35px;
  border-bottom:2px solid #d60362;

}

#posts h2{
  color: #83003C;
}

#posts h3{
  color: #83003C;
  text-decoration:underline;
}

#posts h4{
  color: #83003C;
  font-style: italic;
}

#post-contenido{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin: 15px;
}

#wb_footer{
  height:50px;
  padding-top:20px;
}

#posts :after{
  width:100%;
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>Desarrollo de Aplicaciones Web | Programación</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link  rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>


<body>

  <div id="container">

    <header class="page-header">

      <h1>
        <a href="">Desarrollo de Aplicaciones Web</a>
      </h1>

      <p class="strapline">Programación</p>

      <div id='cssmenu'>
        <ul>
           <li class='active'><a href='#'><span>Indice</span></a></li>
           <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Identificación de los elementos de un programa informático</span></a></li>
           <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Utilización de objetos</span></a>

          </li>

          <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Uso de estructuras de control</span></a>

          </li>

          <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Desarrollo de clases</span></a>

          </li>

          <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Lectura y escritura de información</span></a>

          </li>

          <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Aplicación de las estructuras de almacenamiento</span></a>

          </li>

          <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Utilización avanzada de clases</span></a>

          </li>

          <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Mantenimiento de la persistencia de los objetos</span></a>

          </li>

          <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Gestión de bases de datos relacionales</span></a>

          </li>

          <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Ejercicios</span></a>

          </li>     
        </ul>
      </div>

    </header>

    <div role="main" class="main">

      <div id=posts>
        <h1>Desarrollo Web en entorno cliente</h1>

        <div id=post-contenido>
          <p>Hello World! LALALALALLALA</p>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="contenedor" id="wb_footer" style="background: transparent none repeat scroll left top;">

        <div id="footer" class="elementos">
            <p class="wb-stl-footer">© 2014 <a href="http://alumnodaw.esy.es">alumnodaw.esy.es</a></p>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>


  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Height 100% generally corresponds to 100% of the viewport window, it will not span all content the way you hope to.  Additionally you probably don't need all those floats in there.  You could potential try using a fixed (or absolute) position on the left side with the height: 100% and it will stay as 100% of the viewport.  Since this is tagged as jQuery as well - you could derive the height of the content and set the left side - or generate a background image of the pink stripe and set that on body.

Also check this: http://webdesign.about.com/od/csstutorials/f/set-css-height-100-percent.htm

Comment: This is kind of tl;dr. Stripping this down to a *short* example that demonstrates your problem will make it easier for people to help you, increase the chance that they'll actually bother to help you, and make your question more useful to future visitors. You may well also find that in the process of creating a minimal example, you have a breakthrough and come to understand your problem.

Comment: @JoshuaChavanne Thank you for your answer! I originally planned to use a fixed header, but since my menu is too big I find very problematic using that...I tried with overflow-y but I don't really like how it looks, though the problem is gone apparently.

Comment: @MarkAmery thanks for your advice, I removed many parts of my html that I think they're irrelevant to clean up my code so it can be more readable. It's my first time asking here, so I'm a bit lost.

Comment: @AlisonLopez http://api.jquery.com/height/ get the height of current page and use the height as the height of header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general terms I find `height:100%` of little use, and also it doesn't do what you would expect...

Instead I would suggest to use absolute positioning.

---

I did recreate your base layout using absolute positioning, the following is the HTML mockup:

```
<div id="container">
    <header class="page-header">
        <h1>Ejemplo de Pagina Web</h1>
        <p>Programación</p>
        <div id="cssmenu">
            <ul>
                <li>Item</li>
                <li>Item</li>
                <li>Item</li>
                <li>Item</li>
                <li>Item</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="main">
        <div id="posts">
            <h1>Programación</h1>
            <div id="post-contenido">
                <p>Prueba aaaaaaaaaaaaaalalalallalalalallaa</p>
            </div>
            <div class="contenedor">
                <div id="footer">
                    <p>CC-BY theraot</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
.page-header {
    position:absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 75%;
    background:#d60362;
    color:white;
}
.main {
    position:absolute;
    left: 25%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
#footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

You cee see it at [this custom CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbxQLj).

---

Addendum 1:

If you want to stay with the idea of the `footer` always at the bottom of the page, You probably will want to use `.contenedor` instead of `#footer` for the CSS selector and set a known height to it (to the `contenedor` div), so you can give a known bottom to the `posts` div.
On the other hand, remove the part about the `footer` and let it be just after the `posts`.

Addendum 2:

If you want a layout that will adapt to small view ports by allowing the header to stay on top of the rest of the page (in which condition all the matter of the height is pointless since the header is no longer side by side with the content) then I would suggest to use media queries.

Comment: Thankyou, your answer really helped me...You miss only one thing to work: I needed to give my #container an absolute position...with that and your solution, I solved my problem :)

Answer (score -1):

Remove the property(width: 20%;) on the css class(.page-header).

Answer (score -1):

height 100% means adjust the heght to the size of the screen.
Since you want to adjust it to the size of the content you should be carefull when you use it.
you can also add posifion: fixed; overflow-y: auto to the header gives a better result

But you will stil have problems making that responsive, min-width is a must like that.

take a look at http://getbootstrap.com/
with a few tags and classes you can make beatiful responsive websites